# How to identify the mechanism that makes the program read only data (content of .rodata section) starting address to be 0x100000000 during execution?

Tags: solana-program, solana-test-validator, solana-sdk

Quoting the Solana documentation [1];

The virtual address memory map used by Solana BPF programs is fixed and laid out as follows

- Program code starts at `0x100000000`
- Stack data starts at `0x200000000`
- Heap data starts at `0x300000000`
- Program input parameters start at `0x400000000`

Using a modified version of the Solana helloworld example [2], our custom log function displays the address of the string before calling the original `sol_log` macro.
In the program `helloworld.so`, the initial static string addresses stored in the `.rodata` section are as follow:

```
llvm-objdump -s -j .rodata dist/program/helloworld.so

Contents of section .rodata:
 ...
 0820 6d206964 00486172 64636f64 65645265  m id.HardcodedRe
                                                ^ (0x0820+0x5)
 0830 61644f6e 6c794461 74610048 656c6c6f  adOnlyData.Hello
                                                      ^ (0x0830+0xb)
 0840 21004865 6c6c6f77 6f726c64 20432070  !.Helloworld C p
                                             ^ (0x0840+0x2)
 0850 726f6772 616d2065 6e747279 706f696e  rogram entrypoin
 0860 74004772 65657465 64206163 636f756e  t.Greeted accoun
 ...
```

From the llvm-objdump command above;

- "HardcodedReadOnlyData" static string address is `0x0825`
- "Hello!" static string address is `0x0842`
- "Helloworld C program entrypoint" static string address is `0x0842`

However, when the program is ran, the corresponding static data addresses are different;

- "HardcodedReadOnlyData" static string address is `0x100000825`
- "Hello!" static string address is `0x100000842`
- "Helloworld C program entrypoint" static string is `0x100000842`

We can see that each static data have been relocated to another address, with an offset of `0x100_000_000` added to each static data.

Our goal is to

- Identify and understand the mechanism responsible of the relocation of the static data of the `.rodata` section, because we have another program where this relocation does not occur, leading to the static data keeping their original address at run time (i.e "Hello!" address is `0x0842` instead of `0x100000842` during the execution). That issue leads to `Access violation` when manipulating the static string during program execution.
- Make sure that this mechanism is activated when executing the erroneous program
  Thanks

[1]

https://docs.solana.com/developing/on-chain-programs/overview

[2]

```
  void custom_log(const char * arg1) {
    sol_log_64(42, 42, 42, 42, (uint64_t)arg1);  
    sol_log(arg1);
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above relocation process is performed by the solana rbpf [1] component in `src/elf.rs` line `893` loop.

```
// non relevant parts of the code have been skipped
for relocation in elf.dynamic_relocations() {
    match BpfRelocationType::from_x86_relocation_type(relocation.r_type()) {
        Some(BpfRelocationType::R_Bpf_64_Relative) => {
            if refd_addr < ebpf::MM_PROGRAM_START {
                // The linker hasn't already placed rodata within
                // MM_PROGRAM_START, so we do so now
                refd_addr = ebpf::MM_PROGRAM_START.saturating_add(refd_addr);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The purpose of this code is to iterate through the relocations present in the program `.rel.dyn` section, and add `ebpf::MM_PROGRAM_START` (`0x100000000`) to the corresponding address (crafted from the `offset`)

```
$ llvm-readelf --all dist/program/helloworld.so
    Relocation section '.rel.dyn' at offset 0x26a0 contains 46 entries:
        Offset             Info             Type               Symbol's Value  Symbol's Name
    0000000000000308  0000000000000008 R_SBF_64_RELATIVE                 
    0000000000000320  0000000000000008 R_SBF_64_RELATIVE
```

As showed in the `Info` column above, they are related to the `.symtab` section, which in fine refers to the static strings contained in the `.rodata` section (snippet of `.rodata` available in the post above).

```
Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Address          Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 8] .symtab           SYMTAB          0000000000000000 000968 000270 18     10  24  8
```

The issue with the erroneous program is that the linker `--pack-dyn-relocs=relr` option removes the `R_SBF_64_RELATIVE` data from the `.rel.dyn` section, and add replace them by some `R_SBF_NONE` data in the `.relr.dyn` section. Thus, the addresses of the static strings present in the program are not relocated in the `0x100000000` address space.

As a work-around, removing the linker `--pack-dyn-relocs=relr` option fixed the issue for that program.

[1]

https://github.com/solana-labs/rbpf